# Why my shortcode dont work on website(only work on editor)

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I would like to create a file upload system on my page, I found a code resource from the internet: https://gist.github.com/shamimmoeen/bd577b353446cb8fe519137b164d40e4

However the HTML form only appears on the editor page(I am using Elementor editor), it doesn’t show on the page itself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9w0Q.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p7OG.jpg

Is the code have some problem? Or just WordPress not allow code like this?

Answer (score 1):

To display the code via shortcode you can:

1. Paste your shortcode inside the Elementor WYSIWYG editor

https://elementor.com/help/text-editor-widget/

2. Paste it directly inside the template file with the following code: